# Hibernate : Unknown column in field list

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate

I'am trying to do an unidirectional @OneTaMany relationship like in the [Hibernate User Guide (2.7.2)](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-one-to-many) but when I try to save the following object in a MariaDB Database:

```
Filter filter = new Filter("TLS_A320");
filter.addConstraint(new Constraint(ConstraintType.DEPARTURE, "TLS"));
filter.addConstraint(new Constraint(ConstraintType.AIRCRAFT, "A320"));
session.save(filter);
```

I got this exception :

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'Filter_idFilter' in 'field list'
```

Here are the 2 classes:

**Filter.java**

```
public class Filter {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "idFilter")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Constraint> constraintList;

    //more code
};
```

**Constraint.java**

```
public class Constraint {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "idConstraint")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "type")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
    private ConstraintType constraintType;

    @Column(name = "value")
    private String value;

    //more code
}
```

And here is the tables definition :

```
CREATE TABLE `Constraint` (
    idConstraint INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    type INT NOT NULL,
    value VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY (idConstraint)
);

CREATE TABLE Filter (
    idFilter INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(50) UNIQUE NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY (idFilter)
);

CREATE TABLE Filter_Constraint (
    idFilter INT UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    idConstraint INT NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT fk_Filter_Constraint_Filter FOREIGN KEY (idFilter) REFERENCES Filter(idFilter),
    CONSTRAINT fk_Filter_Constraint_Constraint FOREIGN KEY (idConstraint) REFERENCES `Constraint`(idConstraint)
);
```

It seems to me that that Filter and Constraint insertions are fine and the exception happens when inserting in the Filter_Constraint table :

```
DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - insert into Filter (name) values (?)
DEBUG org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGeneratorHelper - Natively generated identity: 4
DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - insert into `Constraint` (type, value) values (?, ?)
DEBUG org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGeneratorHelper - Natively generated identity: 5
DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - insert into `Constraint` (type, value) values (?, ?)
DEBUG org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGeneratorHelper - Natively generated identity: 6
DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - insert into `Filter_Constraint` (Filter_idFilter, `constraintList_idConstraint`) values (?, ?)
DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - could not execute statement [n/a]
DEBUG com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'Filter_idFilter' in 'field list'
```

I'am pretty new to Hibernate and I just can't figure out what I did wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't define any join column or inverse join column on `constraintList`, hence Hibernate will autogenerate column names which most probably results in the name `Filter_idFilter`.

The entity name will be part of the name since `Constraints` *could* have an id field with the same name, i.e. `idFilter`. Of course *you* know that isn't the case but Hibernate doesn't (or at least the column name generation code isn't that complex) and hence it has to assume that *could* be the case.

The same is true for join table names so you'll probably want to use `@JoinTable` along with the definition of join columns and inverse join columns on `constraintList`. However, since the relation is `OneToMany` anyways, why don't you add a back reference to `Constraint`, add the filter's id to table `Constraint` and get rid of the join table entirely?

Comment: So the exemples given in the user guide do not work ?

Comment: @bl4ckout the examples very likely work but you didn't adapt them correctly. As an example there is a column `Person_id` in table `Person_Phone` because the id column in entity `Person` is defined to be `id`.

Comment: I thought it was `Phone_id` in table Phone too, my bad. I added a reference in Constraint table and class and both @JoinColumn and it works now. Thanks a lot.